# How can I access secure files with express?

Tags: express, handlebars.js, private, secure-coding

```
nodeapp
   -public
            -CSS
                       -style.css
   -pictures
            -secretImage.png
   -views
            -index.hbs
            -login.hbs
            -profile.hbs
   -server.js

const staticFiles = path.join(__dirname, './public')
app.use(express.static(staticFiles))
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
```

I'm keeping my css in the public directory accessed in html  like this:
href="/css/style.css"
which is fine, but I need to store some pictures that should only be available to users that are logged in. If my pictures are in the pictures folder, how can I access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [sendFile](https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.sendFile) method...

```
app.get('/picture/:pictureName', (req, res) => {
     const valid = /* Do your logic to grant access */

     if (valid === false) {
         return res.status(403).send('Not allowed')
     }

     res.sendFile('your file path')
})
```